# How to find unique elements with XQuery?

Tags: xquery

How could I get the list of title books where country location is unique in the next XML?

```
<BooksLib>
  <Book Title="Murder in NY" Year="1980">
    <BookLocations>
      <Location City="New York" Country="USA"/>
       <Location City="Virginia" Country="USA"/>
    </BookLocations>
  </Book >
  <Book  Title="Dracula" Year="2000">
    <BookLocations>
      <Location City="Sydney" Country="Australia"/>
      <Location City="Moab" Country="USA"/>
      <Location City="Calvados" Country="France"/>
    </BookLocations>
  </Book>
  <Book  Title="Romance in calvados" Year="2012">
    <BookLocations>
      <Location City="Calvados" Country="France"/>
    </BookLocations>
  </Book >
</BooksLib>
```

For example, in this XML would be "Dracula", because Australia only appears once

Now I got this:

```html
for $book in doc("books.xml")//Book
where count(distinct-values($Book/BookLocations/Location/@Country)) eq 1
return $Book/data(@Title)
```

But this gives me the titles where the county is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it slightly differently. First, because it feels more natural to me how one actually thinks and second, because it will be faster on a large set. So first I would try to identify which countries are just present once. And then based on this filter out the results. The following should work:

```
let $single-loc :=
  for $loc in doc("books.xml")//Location/@Country/string()
  where count(//Location/@Country[. = $loc]) = 1
  return $loc
for $book in doc("books.xml")//Book
where $book/BookLocations/Location/@Country = $single-loc
return $book/data(@Title)
```

Please note, that your input XML was not well-formed (I edited your post). Also, your XQuery is wrong as `$book` and `$Book` are two different variables.

Comment: Thank you man!! And thanks for correcting the post! I copied wrong.